# Cannot work for 2nd iteration because of writing delay

Tags: visual-c++

My code's IF-THEN does not work for 2nd iteration. This is due to, the jar processing take some time to write it result inside the output.txt.

Since the writing is a bit late, my code's 2nd iteration will always read the previous written value inside the output.txt in order to pass it to the IF-THEN.

For example, in 1st iteration:
output.txt --> 0.9888
twrite.txt --> msg: ok

2nd iteration:
output.txt --> 0.5555
twrite.txt --> msg: ok
//the IF-THEN still gives this result which is based on previous iteration. it should be msg: not ok . since it is < 0.7

I need help, how to solve this 'delay' problem?

```
HRESULT CButtonDemoBHO::onDocumentComplete(IDispatch *pDisp, VARIANT *vUrl){
ATLTRACE("CButtonDemoBHO::onDocumentComplete %S\n", vUrl->bstrVal);

   WinHttpClient client(vUrl->bstrVal);
   client.SendHttpRequest();
   wstring httpResponseHeader = client.GetHttpResponseHeader();
   wstring httpResponse = client.GetHttpResponse();
   writeToLog(httpResponse.c_str());

   if (isMainFrame(pDisp)){
     m_normalPageLoad=false;  

     FILE  *child = _popen("javaw -jar c:\\simmetrics.jar c:\\chtml.txt c:\\thtml.txt  > c:\\output.txt", "r");
fclose(child);

   char readnumber[10];
   float f = 0;

   FILE *file11 = fopen("c:\\output.txt","r");

   char* p = fgets(readnumber,10,file11);
   std::istringstream iss(p);

   iss >> f;


   if (f > 0.7)

    {
        wfstream file12 ("c:\\twrite.txt", ios_base::out);
        file12 << "Msg: ok";
        file12.close();
    }
   else
    {
        wfstream file12 ("c:\\twrite.txt", ios_base::out);
        file12 << "Msg: not ok";
        file12.close();
    }


  iss.clear();
  fclose(file11);

  return S_OK;
  }

  return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to write the output of the JAR to `results.txt`? You can use `_popen` to directly pipe the stream directly instead of writing to the file and reading it into a variable.

Check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b(VS.71).aspx) on `_popen`, they have an example on this.

Also, this would solve your problem of the "writing delay" since you're directly reading the information from the `javaw` application instead of reading it from `output.txt`.